# $.ajax() success called, but will not run method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

This is really puzzling me. Any idea why this would be happening?

This code does work:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'http://localhost:3235/Users/searchUsers?callback=?&searchString=' + searchString,
            success: alert("Success")
        });
```

This code does not:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'http://localhost:3235/Users/searchUsers?callback=?&searchString=' + searchString,
            success: function(data){
              alert("Success");
            }
        });
```

Comment: The code that doesn't work doesn't work because your ajax request itself is failing. The first works because the syntax is wrong and it is calling the alert immediately. The most likely cause of failure here is the service isn't returning valid jsonp.

Comment: As @KevinB mentioned, the request is failing. Changing "success" to "complete" will likely show your alert, but you still need to sort out your request. FWIW, your callback is an `?` in your example.

Comment: @KevinB Okay, thanks. Could this be the case even though the HTTP code is 200 OK and the JSON returned is valid according to JSONLint?

Comment: If it's valid according to JSONLint, then it is JSON and not JSONP. There is a difference!

Comment: @user1729752 JSON shouldn't be returned. You seem to be making a JSONP call (because of the `callback=?`), so the format of the response should be `?(RETURNED_JSON_HERE);`.

Comment: If it's JSONP then you need `datatype: 'jsonp'` and don't need `callback=?` in the url, if it's JSON you need `datatype: 'json'` and don't need `callback=?` in the url.

Comment: @doublesharp You're absolutely right, and that's how I'd do it. But I'm pretty sure if you put `callback=_____` in the URL, jQuery picks up on it and makes it a JSONP request. At least I thought I saw that the other day on here with `$.getJSON()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first snippet is bad syntax and shouldn't be used, you get the alert because it is called immediately, not on success.

There are only two reasons for you to not get the alert with the 2nd snippet.

1. the server isn't returning a success status code, for example, it's either 404, 500, etc, not 200.
2. The only other possibility is the jsonp being returned either isn't jsonp, or isn't valid jsonp.

Most likely you are confusing JSONP with JSON, so i'll give you an example of each. First is json:

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

and this is JSONP `...?callback=somecallbackname&...`:

```
somecallbackname({"foo":"bar"})
```

Note, `somecallbackname` will be supplied by jQuery, you'll have to get the value of the callback get parameter and use it to generate the JSONP accordingly.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I was not aware of the jsonp difference. And since I get a parsererror even with dataType: 'jsonp', I would assume that my issue is serverside. Either I need to get from my local API without 'callback=?' and get JSON, or make it send jsonp, is that right?

Comment: Correct, you need either json, or jsonp. If the request is same-origin, i'd just drop the ?callback=? and use json.

Comment: That gives me: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3235/Users/searchUsers?&searchString=t. Origin http://localhost:3612 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
Serverside problem?

Comment: Nope, that means it's a cross-origin request, so you'll want to use JSONP

Comment: And my API was returning JSON, so there's that. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

The first one "works" because of a bug in your code. It is calling the alert and storing what it returns in the success callback.

Add an error handler to see what the actual problem is.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'http://localhost:3235/Users/searchUsers?callback=?&searchString=' + searchString,
            success: function(data){
              alert("Success");
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, msg) {
              console.log(status, msg);
            }
        });
```

If you can not get the error handler to fire. Look at the net tab on the JavaScript console, and look at the http request. You will see the error that the server returns.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a **bug** though

Comment: @doublesharp Ahh yes, I didn't think of it like that :)

Comment: Error callbacks don't happen with jsonp requests (note the `?callback=?`)

Comment: It's also setting the dataType to JSON but putting a callback in the URL as if it was JSONP

Answer (score 0):

The alert you're getting from your first code snippet is misleading.

When `alert("Success")` is assigned to the `success` property your actually immediately calling it.

You're second approach is the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

The first example is wrong - the result of `alert("Success")` is assigned as the callback, not a function.

Your second example is closer, but you are mixing up JSON and JSONP. If your service is returning JSON, you should remove `callback=?` from your request url (actually, you can remove this regardless, setting `dataType:'jsonp'` will add it automatically).

```
var ajax_url = 'http://example.com:3235/Users/searchUsers?searchString=' + searchString;

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: ajax_url,
    success: function(data){
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error){
        alert("Error: " + status + " " + error);
    },
    complete: function(xhr, status){
        alert("Complete: " + status);
    }
});
```